# Count ifs based on multiple criteria and date

Tags: excel, countif, sumifs

I need help creating a countifs formula (maybe I need a sumifs, not sure) with multiple criterias.

I have an absentee spreadsheet where I track the following: "vacation" day (V), "sick" day (S) and "other" (O) daily on a monthly basis. I have my formula to add the monthly total count of all "V", "S" and "O" but want it to add only to "today's date."

My dates are on cell B1:AF1

The data are on cells B2:AF2, B3:AF3 and so forth

My total cell are on AG2,AG3 and so forth

So far I have the following formula:

```
=COUNTIF(B2:AF2,"=O")+COUNTIF(B2:AF2,"=S")+COUNTIF(B2:AF2,"=V")
```

I need to add the TODAY function and that is where I am having the issue.

I do not work much with the count if formulas or the today function.

Comment: First, take out the '=' inside your COUNTIF ("O" instead of "=O') as it will not return what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this standard (*non-array*) formula,

```
=SUM(COUNTIFS(B2:AF2, {"S","V","O"}, B$1:AF$1, "<"&TODAY()))
```

Fill down as necessary. I'm not entirely sure from your narrative whether that `<` should be a `<=` or not.

In the following image, the S, V and O are counted from the left portion of the matrix (date in row 1 less than today) while the save notations on the right hal are discarded.

[image: HOLIDAYS_UP_TO_TODAY]

Comment: Thank you Jeeped! However, when executing the formula I get a 0 and should be 1 or more.

Comment: Then your dates are probably not true dates. I used `=DATE(2016, 3, COLUMN()-1)` in B1, formatted as `mmm dd` and filled right.

Comment: Got it. Thank you so much for your help!